# IdentityDbContext<TUser> in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework hide base DbContext constructors

Tags: visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am using Visual Studio 2013 RTM with asp.net mvc 5 entity framework asp net identity provider
I am doing the following

```
    public class MyContext : IdentityDbContext<MyUser>
    {
        public MyContext (DbCompiledModel model):base(model)
        {


        }    

        public DbSet<Foo> Foos{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<Bar> Bars{ get; set; }   

    }
```

and getting a compile time error on this line

```
public MyContext (DbCompiledModel model):base(model)
```

The class IdentityDbContext has hide all the constructors of DbContext.
Are there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

IdentityDbContext has only two constructors

- IdentityDbContext()
- IdentityDbContext(String connectionString)

As you are inheriting the IdentityDbContext, you need to follow its available guidance. So, you cannot use DbCompiledModel to construct the context.

Comment: Is there any other way i can use asp.net identity without inheriting with IdentityDbContext

Comment: its a bad design from microsoft

Comment: MS provided application frameworks consider most useful features with medium level of complexity. For more advanced usecase and features requirement in different patterns, you can always make custom version of that framework using its interfaces. The implementation of ASPNET.Identity.EntityFramework itself is using those interfaces.